# I defy the gravity. Yet, I don't

Tags: riddle

This is my Second riddle I'm posting here. I hope you'll have fun!

> I defy the gravity (in your view),
>   But, actually I don't, as I've mass$^{\Pi}$.
>
> I don't like to eat solids,
>   So, I slurp them up.
>
> Who am I?
>   <sub>$^{\Pi}$I can weigh as much as a puppy.</sub>

Hint:

> Scarlett Johansson is the most venomous woman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New answer based on the hint:

> A spider  (because Scarlett Johansson plays in the Marvel films the Black Widow, which is a spider)

I defy the gravity (in your view),
But, actually I don't, as I've massΠ.

> The spiders appear to be in the air but actually they hang on their spiderweb. And some of them could be quite big and heavy.

I don't like to eat solids,
So, I slurp them up.

> That's how they eat their prey.

Comment: Nice approach, but it isn't the answer as clouds _actually_ defy the gravity. I've added a hint. Good luck!

Comment: @rv7 I studied physics and I can asure you that clouds actually don't defy gravity. The fall constantly but very slowly as they drift in the sky.

Comment: **Marvel**lous!! You're right :)

Comment: "I can weigh as much as a puppy -- this would have to be a really small puppy, no?

Comment: @jafe I googled it. 170 grams apparently is the biggest one. Is it enough for a puppy?

Comment: @rhsquared Apparently chihuahua puppies weigh only "[a few ounces](http://www.petchidog.com/chihuahua-growth-chart)", so at least some exist that are lighter than the largest spider. Scary thought...

Answer (score 4):

Are you a:

> blackhole? It defies gravity but does have Mass..and it sucks away all the solids

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> a balloon?

I defy the gravity (in your view),

> Gravity pulls things down, yet balloons go up

But, actually I can't as I've mass.

> Very small though.

I don't like to eat solids,
So, I slurp them up

> You can make water balloons, but a solid filling wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Good start, but it isn't the answer. I'd said that it _seems_ to defy gravity.